# mit-scheme multiple regex matches in string

Tags: regex, scheme, mit-scheme

I'm using MIT/GNU Scheme 9.2. If I define a string:

```
(define a-string "00:00 11:11 22:22")
```

I can match and get the first time a pattern appears:

```
(re-match-extract a-string
              (re-string-match
               "..:.." a-string) 0)
;Value 3: "00:00"
```

That's great, but I want to match the other times "..:.." appears. It seems like there should be some simple way, but am I missing something? Do I need to write a recursive function that matches the first pattern then cuts it off and runs the match on the rest of the string until it's exhausted?

What I would like to end up with is a list that looks like:

```
("00:00" "11:11" "22:22")
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point between when 9.2 was current and now (11.2 is the most recent version as of this writing), the [regular expression support of MIT-Scheme was overhauled](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-ref/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions), and the questions' `re-XXX` functions no longer exist. Instead, it supports some [basic matching functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-ref/Regsexp-Procedures.html) and [SRFI-115 regular expressions](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-115/srfi-115.html), both using different variations of a s-expression based syntax instead of traditional stringy REs. So this is really a "How to get a list of all matches using SRFI-115" answer.

The key here is [`regexp-fold`](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-115/srfi-115.html#proc-regexp-fold), which invokes a function for each non-overlapping match in a string:

```lisp
(define (all-matches re str)
  (regexp-fold re
               (lambda (i match s matches)
                 (cons (regexp-match-submatch match 0) matches))
               '()
               str
               (lambda (i match s matches) (reverse! matches))))

;;; Returns: ("00:00" "11:11" "22:22")
(all-matches (rx any any #\: any any)  "00:00 11:11 22:22")
```